How to retrieve my token that was suppose to be sent as a ERC-20 not a BEP-20 sent to BTCC from trust wallet
I've checked youtube and tried but am not succeeding in getting the actual funds back. I sent from my trust wallet to BTCC's given wallet deposit addresss but they don't actually have tokens on their platform which is confusing. They said they could try to recover for a fee but will most likely lose majority of the amount which sounds shady to me. I have a pool of 5 people's money invested into this and am going to be in a lot of trouble if I can't recover and fix this. Been trying for almost 24 hours now and am exhausted and my head hurts. Please help me. There isn't phrase codes on the BTCC, I tried creating 3 new tokens now on the trust wallet and even media fox. I have mimic'd the token perfectly that it showed up but no funds were part of it. What am I doing wrong? Please, I need a trusted person to help me get this done!!!

This question has been asked many times. I saw the same one 2 days ago here. Please research before hand.

Unfortunately the only way to recover funds is using the private key of the recipient address. It is quite common exchanges to support only popular networks, so if you sent using an unsupported network they might not offer recovery services.
